# How to display appending data without refresh in tree

Tags: php, jquery, codeigniter, treeview

This is my tree view

[image]

I have already done that when i do right click tree name(For example ,Asset, Non Current , Shah) and click add head Then there will come jquery dialog form and I add head code and head name and it is saved successfully in mysql database using codeigniter frame work in php.

Basically , it is created subhead under head.

I need when after submitting, it will be display subhead under that head without refresh tree. For Example ,

If i create subhead under asset then append subhead after "104-Kamrul" without refresh and Display without Change.

How can i solve it, Please any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

i think you need ajax to make what you need, just use a specific class for each tree parent for example:

```
<div class="parent-1">
<div class="child-1"></div>
<div class="child-2"></div>
</div>
<div class="parent-2">
<div class="child-1"></div>
<div class="child-2"></div>
</div>
```

now just load what you need following parents classess:

```
$('.parent-1').children('.child-1').load('http://site.com/url/to/load/new/childs');
```

or

```
var _childs = $.get('http://site.com/url/to/get/some/childs');
$('.parent-1').append(_childs);
```

Answer (score 0):

Given the following markup:

```
<div id="tree">
    <ul>
        <li><a href="#">Asset</a>
            <ul>
                <li><a href="#">101-Non Current</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">102-Current Asset</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">103-Abdul Halim Shah</a>
                    <ul>
                        <li><a href="#">10301-Shah</a>
                            <ul>
                                <li><a href="#">1030101</a></li>
                            </ul>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
                <li><a href="#">104-Kamrul</a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">2-Expenses</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

I wrote a couple of jQuery functions to dynamically add new nodes. One adds the node below the selector specified and the other adds it as a sibling:

```
function addSibling(selector, content) {
    var markup = '<li><a href="#">' + content + '</a></li>';
    $(selector).parent().append(markup);
}

function addChild(selector, content){
    var obj = $(selector);
    var markup='<li><a href="#">' + content + '</a></li>';
    var element;
    if ($('ul', selector).length > 0){
        //nested list
        element = obj.find('> ul');
    } else {
        element = obj;
        markup = '<ul>' + markup + '</ul>';
    }
    element.append(markup);
}
```

Although you'll have to adapt them to your code, you can use the following click function to test them:

```
$("#tree ul").click(function (e) {
    //addSibling(e.target, 'new one');
    addChild(e.target, 'new one');
    e.stopPropagation();
});
```

I didn't understand what your variable were, but to get the data to the server without a page load, you can use an ajax function something like the following:

```
$('#form').submit(function() {
    var headCode = $('input[name="headCode"]').val();
    var headName = $('input[name="headName"]').val();
    $.ajax({
        url: "load.php",
        type: 'POST',
        data: {
            head_code: headCode,
            head_name: headName
        },
        cache: false,
        success: function(json){
            alert('loaded');
        }
    });
    return false;
});
```

Comment: Hi,Thanks for comment, Have you understand that Select mean  Appending UL or LI ID , if it is not then Please clear me

Comment: Sorry, but I don't understand. The functions that I provided can append either a UL or LI, depending on what you specify. As far as "ID", I don't know what you mean.